# How to split and extract text from a table that use \t and \n as a delimitator

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I have a table in .txt file that uses \t and \n as a delimitator:

```
Rank    Word    Rank    Word
1   the 126 name
2   of  127 very
3   to  128 through
4   and 129 just
5   a   130 form
```

From this table I need to extract only the words from the 2 and 4 column (ex. `the of to and a name very through just form`).

Here is what I have using JavaScript String split() Method

```
 var str = "1   the 126 name
    2   of  127 very
    3   to  128 through
    4   and 129 just
    5   a   130 form";
 var res = str.split();
 console.log(res);
```

What should I write as a condition in parameter values to obtain why goal. (ex: var str = "1   the 126 name    2   of  127 very    3   to  128 through    4   and 129 just    5   a   130 form";)
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider you have a text file with the content for the table. You could try something like this to achieve your expected output.

**node js code**

```
fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('/temp/table.txt', function (err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;

  var arr = data.toString().split("\r\n");
  var innerArr;
  var word1Arr = [];
  var word3Arr = [];

  for(var i = 1, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
    innerArr = arr[i].split("\t");

    word1Arr.push(innerArr[1]);
    word3Arr.push(innerArr[3]);
  }

  console.log(word1Arr.concat(word3Arr).join(' '));

});
```

**screen capture of the files**

[image]

**EDIT**

consider using `require('os')` to obtain end of line (EOL) character.
Modified code as shown below.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var os = require('os');

var EOL = os.EOL;

fs.readFile('/temp/table.txt', function (err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;

  var arr = data.toString().split(EOL);
  var innerArr;
  var word1Arr = [];
  var word3Arr = [];

  for(var i = 1, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
    innerArr = arr[i].split("\t");

    word1Arr.push(innerArr[1]);
    word3Arr.push(innerArr[3]);
  }

  console.log(word1Arr.concat(word3Arr).join(' '));

});
```

Comment: I am trying to do exactly what you have showed above and nothing appears http://postimg.org/image/jagjvm6hl/ I have tried at different machine and the output is the same. Thank you!

Comment: @Chris I don't have access to mac OS to try. It works on Windows for me. Did you try it on Windows? I have did some edit to reflect the end of line (based on different OS). Not sure about the \t tab though. I would suggest to check your file paths as well. Also put console.log in the code and try to figure out the output at different  points. By this you should be able to follow what is causing the issue.

Comment: Thank's on windows works, interesting why on OS dosen't. But if I want the output to be saved in a file?

Comment: I managed here is the code for saving them into a file var contents = fs.writeFile("./data.txt",word1Arr.concat(word3Arr).join(' '),
   function(error){
    console.log("written file");
   }
  );

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex

```
/(?:\t)([a-z]+)/g
```

This will match all the alphabets which are followed by tab.

[**Regex Online Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/qX2eA9/2)

```js
var str = 'Rank    Word    Rank    Word\
1 the 126 name\
2 of 127 very\
3 to 128 through\
4 and 129 just\
5 a 130 form';


var regex = /(?:\t)([a-z]+)/g;
var words = [];

while (res = regex.exec(str)) {
  words.push(res[1]);
}

console.log(words);
```

Comment: Thank you but your output will be [ '\tthe',
  '\tname',
  '\tof',
  '\tvery',
  '\tto',
  '\tthrough',
  '\tand',
  '\tjust',
  '\ta',
  '\tform' ] But I need it to be like this (the of to and a name very through just form) How can I get in this format?

Comment: Thank you, but I have this error (document is not defined). I am using node to run the .js file

Comment: @Chris The last two lines are added for showing the result here on the page for DEMO purpose, dont use it

Comment: Thank you, but in case I want the result to be delimited not by "," but by space how can I do it?

Comment: @Chris at the end `words.join(' ')`

Comment: I am trying to run your code puting it into a file.js and then from terminal using command node file.js. and I have this error ReferenceError: document is not defined. What should I do>? Thank you. May be I need to import some library?

Comment: @Chris, obviously `document` isn't available when you run scripts thru command line. As mentioned earlier, `document.write(..)` is only for the sake of demo. Remove that line, save your file and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Without regex and getting everything at the 2nd and 4th column (special characters, numbers, whatever) :

```js
var input, lines, words;

input = "Rank Word Rank Word\n1 the 126 name\n2 of 127 very\n3 to 128 through\n4 and 129 just\n5 a 130 form";
words = [];

lines = input.split('\n');
// remove headers
lines.shift();

lines.forEach(function(line, i) {
   var tmp = line.split('\t');
   words.push(tmp[1], tmp[3]);
});

// the alert is there so you can use the 'Run code snippet' button below
// use console.log in nodejs
alert(words.join('  '));
```